# AngularFire2 Authentication Error: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

I am trying to make login and signup forms for my web app using angularFire2 and Firebase.

I am getting an error when taking a users signup information and passing it into the signInWithEmailAndPassword function.

`signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.`

I have everything in my component that deals with the email variable typed as a string and it logs to the console as a string so I am not sure exactly what is going on.

I have researched for almost 3 hours now and cant find anything that could fix the issue.

Template:

```
<form action="" class="login">
   <input type="email" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="email" [(ngModel)]="signInEmail">
   <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="signInPassword">
    <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    <button type="submit" (click)="login(signInEmail, signInPassword)">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
// Sign In
  signInEmail: string;
  signInPassword: string;

  constructor(private _songsService: SongService, private _router: Router, public af: AngularFire) {
    this.backgroundImage = '../images/main-bg.jpg';
    this.logoIcon = '../images/logo-icon.png';
  }

  login(email, password) {
    console.log('login');
    this.af.auth.login( email, password );
  }
```

NgModule

```
const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Password,
  method: AuthMethods.Password
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig)
```

Comment: Can you post the email you are trying to login with? Maybe it's an invalid one.

Comment: It's my own personal email and it is a valid email.

Comment: Did you try a `console.log`(email,password)` in the login function?

Comment: I have tried other email addresses as well. Even other ones that I own but aren't my primary account and I get the same error.

Comment: Yes and I am getting back the email and password in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for `af.auth.login()` is one object with two properties:

```
// Email and password
af.auth.login({
  email: 'email@example.com',
  password: 'password',
},
{
  provider: AuthProviders.Password,
  method: AuthMethods.Password,
})
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md

> ... if you're using username and password, then you'll have to call af.auth.login() with the user's credentials.
>
> af.auth.login({ email: 'email', password: 'pass' });

Comment: Yup! You're right lol. Totally missed the object in there! Thank you!