# AngularFire Auth error: "signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First agument "email" must be a valid sring."

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have been trying to make the firebase auth for months, but the docs after updates do not help and there is little content on the web.

[Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02gqA.jpg)

Briefly, this is the error. I researched, the content about this error is referring to an old update on promise, [and this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118652/angularfire2-authentication-error-first-argument-email-must-be-a-valid-string), which is about angularfire2, still did not help me.

View:

```
   <form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form" class="form-signin">      
     <hr class="colorgraph"><br>

    <input type="text" id="login-username" ng-model="loginEmail" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="email" autofocus="" />
    <input type="password" ng-model="loginPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>          

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  name="Submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" type="Submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'FBMSG', 'authFactory', function($scope, FBMSG, authFactory) {


$scope.login = function () {
var email = $scope.loginEmail;
var password = $scope.loginPassword;

    var result = authFactory.authUser(email, password);
  result.then(function(authData){
     console.log("User Successfully logged in with uid: ", authData.uid)
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Authentication Failed: ", error)
  })
}   }]);
```

Service:

```
app.factory('authFactory', ['FBMSG', '$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', function(FBMSG, $firebase, $firebaseAuth) {
var authFactory = {};
var auth = $firebaseAuth();
console.log(auth);

authFactory.createUser = function(email, password) {
    return auth.$createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password
    })};

 // Authentication
 authFactory.authUser = function(email, password) {
    return auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword({
                  email: email,
                  password: password
            });
 }
return authFactory; }]);
```

Infos: `Firebase v3.9.0` `AngularJS v1.6.4`